# Bitmasking in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, bit-manipulation

I'd like to learn bit masking. As far as I understand, it is means to store binary values of certain type into one variable.

If the above assumption is true, I figured I could do something like this:

```
typedef NSUInteger Traits;

enum
{
    TraitsCharacterHonest       = 0,
    TraitsCharacterOptimistic   = 1,
    TraitsCharacterPolite       = 4,
    TraitsCharacterDevious      = 8,
    TraitsPhysicalTall          = 16,
    TraitsPhysicalBeautiful     = 32,
    TraitsPhysicalFat           = 64,
    TraitsPhysicalBigEyes       = 128,
    TraitsPhysicalRedHair       = 256, 
};

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  *name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) Traits    *traits;

@end
```

**Question 1** is, how do I assign more traits to one person?

**Question 2** is, do I have to put ever increasing numbers to enum items, or is there a way to indicate this?

Ultimately I want to achieve something like this:

```
Person *john = [[Person alloc] init];

//here code that assigns john three traits: TraitsCharacterHonest,      
//TraitsCharacterOptimistic and TraitsPhysicalBeautiful.
```

If I understand it correctly, the value of

john.traits should be 100011., reading from right and each place representing that particular enum value / trait..and 0 meaning not having it and 1 meaning having it.

Can you please advice on syntax and explain a particular aspect if needed?

Comment: Is it intentional, that `TraitsCharacterHonest` has a numeric value of zero? You cannot work with zeros here, since `x & 0 == 0` for any integer `x`, i.e., this trait would never be present for any person. No honest people in that world. Sad place...

Comment: It's just like plain old C -- there are no special facilities in Objective-C for bit-significant values.

Comment: It's not intentional, I did not realised it. Of course, the first item has to have a value of 1.
The proper sequence is powers of 2, yes?
2to0, 2 to1, 2to2 ie..1,2,4,8,16..etc..

Comment: It is a lot easier to use bit masks made up of hex constants rather than decimal numbers.  So 1 would be 0x0001, 2 would be 0x0002, 16 would be 0x0010, 256 would be 0x0100, etc.  Makes the bit mask much easier to visualize.

Comment: @Dirk, good point about not starting at zero for enumeration.  Typically zero would be used to indicate no traits for a starting point and then you would add various bit masks for the different traits.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I'd recommend changing a few things:

- The enum values can be changed to be a one left-shifted. Makes it a little easier to write, in my opinion.
- You don't need to typedef to NSUInteger, you can declare a enum type directly using `typedef enum`.
- And, as other people have mentioned, your property shouldn't be a pointer to a Traits type.

My code would look like this:

```
typedef enum
{
    TraitsCharacterHonest       = 1 << 0,
    TraitsCharacterOptimistic   = 1 << 1,
    TraitsCharacterPolite       = 1 << 2,
    TraitsCharacterDevious      = 1 << 3,
    TraitsPhysicalTall          = 1 << 4,
    TraitsPhysicalBeautiful     = 1 << 5,
    TraitsPhysicalFat           = 1 << 6,
    TraitsPhysicalBigEyes       = 1 << 7,
    TraitsPhysicalRedHair       = 1 << 8
} Traits;

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString  *name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) Traits     traits;

@end
```

Setting John's traits will look like this:

```
Person *john = [[Person alloc] init];

john.traits = TraitsCharacterHonest | TraitsCharacterOptimistic | TraitsPhysicalBeautiful;
```

However, while bit-fields are useful to learn, but they're a real pain to debug. If you want to go and print 
this character's traits now, you'll have to write code like this:

```
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];

if (self.traits & TraitsCharacterHonest)
{
    [result appendString: @"Honest, "];
}
if (self.traits & TraitsCharacterOptimistic)
{
    [result appendString: @"Optimistic, "];
}
if (self.traits & TraitsCharacterPolite)
{
    [result appendString: @"Polite, "];
}
// etc...
```

Additionally, syntax for operations like removing a trait are confusing. You'll have to use `&` and a NOT-ed constant,

```
// remove 'Tall' trait
john.traits = john.traits & ~TraitsPhysicalTall
```

If you can (and performance isn't too much of a issue), I'd prefer using a higher-level feature. Perhaps an NSSet with string constants? e.g.

```
__unused static NSString *TraitsCharacterHonest = @"TraitsCharacterHonest";
__unused static NSString *TraitsCharacterOptimistic = @"TraitsCharacterOptimistic";
__unused static NSString *TraitsCharacterPolite = @"TraitsCharacterPolite";
// etc...

@interface Person : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString     *name;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSMutableSet *traits;

@end
```

Then you can do:

```
// adding
[john.traits addObject: TraitsCharacterHonest];
// checking
[john.traits containsObject: TraitsCharacterHonest];
// removing 
[john.traits removeObject: TraitsCharacterHonest];
```

Makes more sense to me. What's more, you can print the description of the traits directly with

```
NSLog(@"John's traits: %@", john.traits);
```

and you'll get reasonable output.

Comment: I really appreciate your example. 
Perhaps it wasn't fortunate from me to use Person to learn this, since in a real-world project (I cannot give hints to problem domain unfortunately for legal reasons) I need by each particular enum item to indicate an answer to a particular question. So the context is not  that person has SOME traits of a set, but what are the values (YES or NO) for each of the questions. (1 question = 1 enum item with 0 or 1)

It is rendering your proposal a bit less suitable then. I am not sure though..is it?

Comment: Hmm. In this case, I'd use an NSDictionary. Use string constants as above as the keys to the dictionary, and use NSNumber bool objects to store the answers.

Comment: I would also recommend putting a `FlagsMask` suffix on each variable, indicating that the variable has a bit (or bits, if you combine them... `BoldItalicTraitsMask = `BoldTraitsMask | ItalicTraitsMask`) set and can be used as a mask.

Comment: For setting and clearing the bits I would use an inline function or a macro which would provide a fairly clear indication of what is being done due to the name of the function or macro.  And it also makes it easier to find places where the bit is being cleared or set as well.

Comment: Excellent example.  Thanks for taking the time to do this.

Comment: Is there a way to check the first value in the bitmask like if:

John.traits = TraitsCharacterHonest | TraitsCharacterOptimistic | TraitsPhysicalBeautiful;

I need to check if the first trait of John is TraitsCharacterHonest.

Comment: No sorry @jeraldo, bitmasks don't have an order. You'll probably be better off with an NSArray containing NSString constants.

Answer (score 4):

One issue that you can run into is that using bit masks to indicate membership within sets can be capped by the number of bits in the underlying data type.  For instance an unsigned long of 32 bits has room only for 32 disjoint or different members.  If you need to add a 33rd, you are out of luck unless you go to a 64 bit unsigned integer.

One workaround for this is to use an array of bytes.  With this approach you have to specify your bit membership as two pieces of data, the offset to the byte and the bit mask to use for the specific bit.

I have also seen people use byte arrays for single membership so that rather than one bit used, the entire byte is used.  It can be a waste of memory but then it may be that it is more flexible and useful and the amount of memory wasted is not a problem.

For using an array of bytes to hold the set of bits, you might consider using an unsigned long to represent the members of the set in which the least significant byte is the bit mask and the rest of the bytes are used as an unsigned 3 byte offset into the byte array.  You would then do something like the following:

```
int getBitSet (unsigned char *bArray, unsigned long ulItem)
{
    unsigned long ulByteOffset = ((ulItem >> 8) & 0x00ffffff);
    unsigned char ucByteMask = (ulItem & 0x000000ff);

    return (*(bArray + ulByteOffset) & ucByteMask);
}

int setBitSet (unsigned char *bArray, unsigned long ulItem, unsigned long ulNewValue)
{
    unsigned char oldValue;
    unsigned long ulByteOffset = ((ulItem >> 8) & 0x00ffffff);
    unsigned char ucByteMask = (ulItem & 0x000000ff);

    oldValue = *(bArray + ulByteOffset) & ucByteMask;

    if (ulNewValue) {
        *(bArray + ulByteOffset) |= ucByteMask;  // set bit
    } else {
        *(bArray + ulByteOffset) &= ~ucByteMask;  // clear bit
    }

    return oldValue;
}
```

You could then have a set of functions to get and set the bytes or you could use macros.  With C++ you can create your own class for this functionality and provide various types of logical operations as well so that you can create sets of various kinds and then perform logical operations on the sets.

Comment: This is a very unwieldy solution, and if you are using C++, then a `std::bitset` (or a `std::vector<bool>`) makes more sense here.

Comment: I agree that using what already exists is usually best.  On the other hand if it does not exist then you have to build something.  I provided this as an example of what could be done rather than what should be done.  The question is from someone wanting to learn bit masking operations.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 6 or above, Mac OS X 10.8 and above

You can do:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, Traits) {
    TraitsCharacterHonest,
    TraitsCharacterOptimistic,
    TraitsCharacterPolite,
    TraitsCharacterDevious,
    TraitsPhysicalTall,
    TraitsPhysicalBeautiful,
    TraitsPhysicalFat,
    TraitsPhysicalBigEyes,
    TraitsPhysicalRedHair
};
```

For more info, refer to http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/

Comment: I think your example misses the point completely. true, it is the new form of declaring enumeration, but I am asking about bitmasking here, which is not happening in your example.

Comment: For bitmasks you should use NS_OPTIONS! It even says so in the link you provided.

Comment: @EarlGrey I was actually wanting to say NS_OPTIONS somehow I typed NS_ENUM(very awkward..), I have updated my answer.

Comment: Voted down because this doesn't magically create masks; it still creates the values like a regular enum. You have to supply the mask values, yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Your major issue here is making `traits` a pointer. Drop the pointer, and do it like you would in C:

```
john.traits |= TraitsCharacterOptimistic | TraitsCharacterOptimistic | TraitsCharacterOptimistic;
```

Remember that you only need pointers in a couple of situations in Objective-C:

- When you are dealing with actual objects (derived from `NSObject`)
- When you need to pass a primitive by reference (an `int *` argument to a function to return count), in which case you take the adress of a local variable, and that pointer is not saved by the function.
- When you need an array of primitive types, dynamically allocated on the heap (e.g. using `malloc` & friends).

Otherwise, just use a stack-allocated primitive type, as you can do a lot of things with it.

Comment: that array of primitives doesn't need to be dynamically allocated.

Comment: @H2CO3 of course not, it was just an example of why pointers to primitive types are used.

Comment: Making it a pointer was just muscle memory mistake. Of course, it's a primitive value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all change:

```
...
typedef NSUInteger Traits;

enum
{
    TraitsCharacterHonest = 0, //cann't be a 0
    ...
};
...
@property (assign, nonatomic) Traits *traits; //you no need create a pointer to a primitive type
```

to:
...

```
typedef NSUInteger Traits;

enum
{
    TraitsCharacterHonest = 1, 
    ...
};
...
@property (assign, nonatomic) Traits traits;
```

For assigning you should do follow:

```
john.traits |= TraitsCharacterHonest | TraitsCharacterDevious;
```

Bitwise operations in ObjC are the same like as in `C` language.
Check this tutorial [Bitwise Operators in C and C++: A Tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html)

Comment: And Can I somehow avoid explicitely assigning those powers of 2 to the enum values?
I have seen this 1<<0..is it the syntax i need?

Comment: yeah, you can use this syntax 1<<0, 1<<1, 1<<2 and so on

Comment: do I need to do it for all - or - after the first two..compiler realises that the rule applies to the rest?

Comment: The `1<<N` syntax is for clarity; read it directly as "put a 1 bit into the Nth position".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

`1 << 8` is the same what `100000000`:

```
john.traits = TraitsCharacterHonest | TraitsCharacterOptimistic | TraitsPhysicalBeautiful;
```

is exactly the same as:

```
john.traits = 000000001 | 000000010 | 000100000;
```

and the result is:

```
john.traits = 000100011
```

Now, when you want to check conditional:

```
if (self.traits & TraitsCharacterHonest) { ... }
```

it is equivalent to:

```
if (000100011 & 000000001) { ... }
```

and result of that is:

```
if (000000001) { ... }
```

And, this is actually `1`, `not zero` value is `true`, so the whole conditional is `true`. Enjoy:-)